# How do I correctly print a struct?

Tags: swift, struct

I'm trying to store an array of store structs within my users struct, but I can't get this to print correctly.

```
struct users {
    var name: String = ""
    var stores: [store]
}

struct store {
    var name: String = ""
    var clothingSizes = [String : String]()        
}

var myFirstStore = store(name: "H&M", clothingSizes: ["Shorts" : "Small"])
var mySecondStore = store(name: "D&G", clothingSizes: ["Blouse" : "Medium"])

var me = users(name: "Me", stores: [myFirstStore, mySecondStore])
println(me.stores)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You’re initializing them just fine.  The problem is your `store` struct is using the default printing, which is an ugly mangled version of the struct name.

If you make it conform to `CustomStringConvertible`, it should print out nicely:

```
// For Swift 1.2, use Printable rather than CustomStringConvertible 
extension Store: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        // create and return a String that is how
        // you’d like a Store to look when printed
        return name
    }
}

let me = Users(name: "Me", stores: [myFirstStore, mySecondStore])
println(me.stores)  // prints "[H&M, D&G]"
```

If the printing code is quite complex, sometimes it’s nicer to implement `Streamable` instead:

```
extension Store: Streamable {
    func writeTo<Target : OutputStreamType>(inout target: Target) {
        print(name, &target)
    }
}
```

p.s. convention is to have types like structs start with a capital letter